# SMS Text Message from PC To Mobile Phone in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to send SMS Text messages from a PC to a Mobile phone in C#.....I want to use **Nokia** mobile as my modem .....PC connect with mobile via cable

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind subscribing to an online SMS gateway, many of the providers give you the ability to make a specially crafted HTTP request to send a text message.

It would be fairly trivial to build your own class around .net's WebClient class to interface to the online SMS gateway.

You don't specify your location in your profile, but if you are looking for a UK SMS gateway, I can give you the names of a few companies that do this, as I researched this fairly recently.

Answer (score 1):

it's as easy as installing the USB drivers for the phone, opening the correct comport, and issuing Hayes modem commands to the phone.

[Hayes modem commands](http://www.cellular.co.za/hayesat.htm)  search for 'SMS Command Set' on the page to find what you are looking for